# upload file using form and set filepath to simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, simplexml

I want to upload a file using a form and then get its full path in the directory to call it using `simplexml_load_file()`. I tried this with no positive result:

/home/user-linux/Desktop/web/WebProjectbool(false)

File to upload :**choose File** *data.kml*

**press This to upload**

```
<?php

$filePath = realpath($_FILES["file"]["UploadFileName"]);
echo $filePath;//just to see if i am getting the righ path

$parse = simplexml_load_file($filePath);
var_dump($parse);

?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="example2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p>File to upload : <input type ="file" name = "UploadFileName"></p> 
            <br />
            <input type = "submit" name = "Submit" value = "Press THIS to upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `echo $parse->asXML();` instead of `var_dump();`

Comment: What does "no positive result" mean? What result *did* you get?

Comment: I just want to get the path of the imported file from the form,and pass it to `simplexml_load_file()`.Like **/home/user/Desktop/web/data.xml**

Comment: Yes, but *what happens when you run this code right now*? I have no idea what "no positive result" means; does it mean it echoes `-1`? That your computer lets out a puff of smoke? Is the echo'd file path what you expect? Are there any errors on the screen or in your logs? Please [edit] your question to include more information, remembering that *we do not have access to your computer*, so only know exactly what you tell us.